# Collecting command output in variable for parallel commands

Tags: bash

I want to run few commands in parallel, but then show outputs grouped (not entwined).

So I have error.sh:

```
echo "e1"
sleep 2
echo "e2"
exit 1
```

success.sh:

```
echo "s1";
sleep 1;
echo "s2";
exit 0;
```

and test.sh which I run:

```
./success.sh & success_pid=$!
out=$(./error.sh) & error_pid=$!

wait $success_pid
echo $?
wait $error_pid
echo $?
echo $out

echo "fine :)"
```

But assigning output of second script doesn't work as expected (it's empty). I know I can use files for that, but the interesting question is: why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment happens in a subshell that's spawned to execute the background command, so it doesn't affect the variable in the original shell. Redirect the output to a file.

```
./success.sh & success_pid=$!
./error.sh > /tmp/error.out & error_pid=$!

wait $success_pid
echo  $?
wait $error_pid
echo $?
cat /tmp/error.out

echo "fine :)"
```

Comment: So there's not other way than file (or named pipe, but in the essence it's the same)?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Even if the assignment weren't in the subshell, it would happen when the background command is started, not when it finishes.